# Add links of outside pages to wordpress blog menu.

Tags: wordpress

I have some issue with the WordPress menu.

My website is static HTML and CSS.
my blog is in WordPress. I want to link my static pages to my WordPress blog menu.

How to do this link binding in WordPress?

Thank you

Comment: what was the error you getting in your menus and how you have implemented it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your WordPress admin dashboard, follow these steps:

Appearance -> Menus -> Custom Links -> (Add your URL) -> Add to Menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom links options in wordpress menu to add links of your static html pages in wordpress blog.